# Is there a clever way to pass the key to defaultdict's default_factory?

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

A class has a constructor which takes one parameter:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        ...
```

Somewhere in the code, it is useful for values in a dict to know their keys.
I want to use a defaultdict with the key passed to newborn default values:

```
d = defaultdict(lambda : C(here_i_wish_the_key_to_be))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 173):

It hardly qualifies as *clever* - but subclassing is your friend:

```
class keydefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError( key )
        else:
            ret = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
            return ret

d = keydefaultdict(C)
d[x] # returns C(x)
```

Comment: That's exactly the uglyness I'm trying to avoid... Even using a simple dict and checking for key existence is much cleaner.

Comment: @Paul: and yet this is your answer. Ugliness? Come on!

Comment: I think I'm just going to take that bit of code and put it in my personalized general utilities module so I can use it whenever I want.  Not too ugly that way...

Comment: +1 Directly addresses the OP's question and doesn't look "ugly" to me. Also a good answer because many don't seem to realize that `defaultdict`'s `__missing__()` method can be overridden (as it can in any subclass of the built-in `dict` class since version 2.5).

Comment: No, this answer is a nice suggestion, and useful, but clearly not what the OP is asking for.  The whole point of this question is to avoid exactly this.

Comment: +1 The whole purpose of \_\_missing\_\_ is to customize the behavior for missing keys.  The dict.setdefault() approach mentioned by @silentghost would also work (on the plus side, setdefault() is short and already exists; on the minus side, it suffers from efficiency issues and no one really likes the name "setdefault").

Comment: `dict.setdefault(...)` is a much cleaner way to tackle this.

Comment: I disagree about uglyness, It is ugly if you do not plan to reuse it. But for multiple usages, each instance is a single line.

Comment: any pypi lib has this? does not look ugly but also not fit in app code.

Comment: Note that you can also directly subclass `dict` instead of subclassing `defaultdict`, and provide your own constructor that takes a `default_factory`. If you're using mypy or some other static type-checker, you may have to take this approach; it won't like the code in this answer as written because `defaultdict`'s `default_factory` property to be a callable with no arguments.

Comment: I know it's 10 years later but I love this solution! Easy to grok, relatively elegant, and learned a little bit about Python internals

Comment: @Muposat: the problem with `setdefault` is that you have to pass the actual default value - as opposed to a function that would only be called to generate it if needed - meaning you'll end up needlessly invoking the function / creating a new instance on each invocation.

Comment: Unlike the original poster, I find this method both useful and elegant. Too bad that this much-needed functionality isn't the standard.

Comment: But wouldn't this solution search the key twice (in case it's missing)? One time to discover that it's missing, and then a second time inside __missing__(), when you assign self[key] = ... -- because the assignment automatically searches the key. Right?

Comment: @Amenhotep In both cases there is no search O(n), but an access/write with O(1).

Answer (score 40):

No, there is not.

The `defaultdict` implementation can not be configured to pass missing `key` to the `default_factory` out-of-the-box.  Your only option is to implement your own `defaultdict` subclass, as suggested by @JochenRitzel, above.

But that isn't "clever" or nearly as clean as a standard library solution would be (if it existed). **Thus the answer to your succinct, yes/no question is clearly "No".**

It's too bad the standard library is missing such a frequently needed tool.

Comment: Yep, it would have been a better design choice to let the factory take the key (unary function rather than nullary). It's easy to discard an argument when we want to return a constant.

Comment: Although succinctness is an OK goal (obfuscating jargon and 'big words' are also succinct), I find the `defaultdict` to be necessary rather than nice to have when bootstrapping some automatic built-in (like setting up an object reference cache in a constructor).  Without the connection to the key, the `defaultdict` is much less useful than it could be, and is not so easy to replace w/out the "ugly" workaround.

Answer (score 9):

I just want to expand on [Jochen Ritzel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2912455/995480) with a version that makes typecheckers happy:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")

class keydefaultdict(dict[K, V]):
    def __init__(self, default_factory: Callable[[K], V]):
        super().__init__()
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key: K) -> V:
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        else:
            ret = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
            return ret
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you need `defaultdict` here at all. Why not just use `dict.setdefault` method?

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('p', C('p')).v
'p'
```

That will of course would create many instances of `C`. In case it's an issue, I think the simpler approach will do:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> if 'e' not in d: d['e'] = C('e')
```

It would be quicker than the `defaultdict` or any other alternative as far as I can see.

**ETA** regarding the speed of `in` test vs. using try-except clause:

```
>>> def g():
    d = {}
    if 'a' in d:
        return d['a']


>>> timeit.timeit(g)
0.19638929363557622
>>> def f():
    d = {}
    try:
        return d['a']
    except KeyError:
        return


>>> timeit.timeit(f)
0.6167065411074759
>>> def k():
    d = {'a': 2}
    if 'a' in d:
        return d['a']


>>> timeit.timeit(k)
0.30074866358404506
>>> def p():
    d = {'a': 2}
    try:
        return d['a']
    except KeyError:
        return


>>> timeit.timeit(p)
0.28588609450770264
```

Comment: This is highly wasteful in cases where d is accessed many times, and only rarely missing a key: C(key) will thus create tons of unneeded objects for the GC to collect. Also, in my case there is an additional pain, since creating new C objects is slow.

Comment: @Paul: that's right. I would suggest then even more simple method, see my edit.

Comment: I'm not sure it is quicker than defaultdict, but this is what I usually do (see my comment to THC4k's answer). I hoped there is a simple way to hack around the fact default_factory takes no args, to keep the code slightly more elegant.

Comment: @Paul: of course it's faster! it's a single `in` statement! It is also clean and readable. `defaultdict` has just different intention behind it.

Comment: it is an 'if k in d' vs. (a hidden) 'try: d[k] except KeyError'; CPython's implementation is very fast with exceptions, so should be on the same speed level.

Comment: @Paul: you understand that these are different pieces of coded, right? Additionally, `in` would always be faster that the try-except clause.

Comment: Exceptions are as fast as tests. This is one of the reasons BTAFTP exists alongside LBYL. (Although it turned out to be implementation-specific: IronPython is extremely slow with exceptions, due to .NET design).

Comment: @SilentGhost: I don't understand - how does this solve the OP's problem? I thought OP wanted any attempt to read `d[key]` to return `d[key] = C(key)` if `key not in d`. But your solution requires him to actually go and pre-set `d[key]` in advance? How would he know which `key` he'd need?

Comment: Awesome! No ugly code and only uses standard dict: `D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D`

Comment: Because setdefault is ugly as hell and the defaultdict from collection SHOULD suport a factory function which receive the key. What a wasted oportunity from the Python designers!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example of a dictionary that automatically adds a value. The demonstration task in finding duplicate files in /usr/include. Note customizing dictionary *PathDict* only requires four lines:

```
class FullPaths:

    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.paths = set()

    def record_path(self,path):
        self.paths.add(path)

class PathDict(dict):

    def __missing__(self, key):
        ret = self[key] = FullPaths(key)
        return ret

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pathdict = PathDict()
    for root, _, files in os.walk('/usr/include'):
        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(root,f)
            pathdict[f].record_path(path)
    for fullpath in pathdict.values():
        if len(fullpath.paths) > 1:
            print("{} located in {}".format(fullpath.filename,','.join(fullpath.paths)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can potentially achieve the desired functionality is by using decorators

```py
def initializer(cls: type):
    def argument_wrapper(
        *args: Tuple[Any], **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Callable[[], 'X']:
        def wrapper():
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return argument_wrapper


@initializer
class X:
    def __init__(self, *, some_key: int, foo: int = 10, bar: int = 20) -> None:
        self._some_key = some_key
        self._foo = foo
        self._bar = bar

    @property
    def key(self) -> int:
        return self._some_key

    @property
    def foo(self) -> int:
        return self._foo

    @property
    def bar(self) -> int:
        return self._bar

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'[Key: {self.key}, Foo: {self.foo}, Bar: {self.bar}]'
```

Then you can create a `defaultdict` as so:

```py
>>> d = defaultdict(X(some_key=10, foo=15, bar=20))
>>> d['baz']
[Key: 10, Foo: 15, Bar: 20]
>>> d['qux']
[Key: 10, Foo: 15, Bar: 20]
```

The `default_factory` will create new instances of `X` with the specified
arguments.

Of course, this would only be useful if you **know** that the class will be used in a `default_factory`. Otherwise, in-order to instantiate an individual class you would need to do something like:

```py
x = X(some_key=10, foo=15)()
```

Which is kind of ugly... If you wanted to avoid this however, and introduce a degree of complexity, you could also add a keyword parameter like `factory` to the `argument_wrapper` which would allow for generic behaviour:

```py
def initializer(cls: type):
    def argument_wrapper(
        *args: Tuple[Any], factory: bool = False, **kwargs: Dict[str, Any]
    ) -> Callable[[], 'X']:
        def wrapper():
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)

        if factory:
            return wrapper
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)

    return argument_wrapper
```

Where you could then use the class as so:

```py
>>> X(some_key=10, foo=15)
[Key: 10, Foo: 15, Bar: 20]
>>> d = defaultdict(X(some_key=15, foo=15, bar=25, factory=True))
>>> d['baz']
[Key: 15, Foo: 15, Bar: 25]
```