# Using append method in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm currently looking at this code snippet from *Think Python* implementing an inverted dictionary with the setdefault method, and I'm unclear on why it works:

```
def invert_dict(d):
"""Inverts a dictionary, returning a map from val to a list of keys.

If the mapping key->val appears in d, then in the new dictionary
val maps to a list that includes key.

d: dict

Returns: dict
"""
    inverse = {}
    for key, val in d.iteritems():
        inverse.setdefault(val, []).append(key)
    return inverse
```

Reading from left to right in the for loop, `inverse.setdefault(val, [])` creates an entry in the dictionary, not a list. So how can we use the append method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use cases for the 'setdefault' dict method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method)

Comment: Also see [the documentation on `setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the append method, because setdefault itself returns the value of dict[val] after initializing it if necessary.  So the first time setdefault is called on a particular dictionary key, it sets inverse[val] to the second parameter (the empty list) *and then returns that empty list*.  That is the list you are appending to.

This particular paradigm is out of date for this particular use-case, btw.  The best way to do it now is:

```
import collections
inverse = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, val in d.items():
    inverse[val].append(key)
```

The reason is that setdefault creates a new empty list object every time through the list, and then immediately discards the newly created object if inverse[val] already exists.

Also, iteritems() is still more efficient for Python 2, but it doesn't exist in Python 3 and items() in Python 3 works the same as iteritems() in Python 2.