# How does .setdefault() work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using 'setdefault()' in my program but I'm not sure what it actually does...
so I'm asking on here if anyone one knows?

```
set default
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use cases for the 'setdefault' dict method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method)

Comment: Did you look at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) already? If so, please indicate which part of that documentation you need help understanding. (And if not, please do!)

Comment: As an aside, it's not a good idea to use things in your program(s) that you don't understand. The goal is to understand your program and have a (correct!) mental model of how it works. So, +1 for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are *[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault)*.

`dict.setdefault()` is something like the "lvalue" analog of `dict.get()`, which is typically an "rvalue" (occurs on the righthand side of assignments — it retrieves a value, as opposed to mutating the state of something).

Informally, `d.setvalue(key, value)` means "Give me `d[key]`. What, `key` isn't in `d`? OK, then assign `d[key] = value`, just in time; *now* give me `d[key]`."

Suppose `d = {'a': 17}`. Then

```
>>> d.setdefault('a', 0)
17
```

Here, `'a'` is in `d`, so `d.setdefault('a', 0)` leaves `d` unchanged and returns `d['a']`. However,

```
>>> d.setdefault('b', 100)
100
```

Because `b` is not in `d`, `d.setdefault('b', 100)` returns 100 *and* sets `d[b] = 100`. `d` now has two items, and both `a` and `b` are keys:

```
>>> len(d), d['a'] == 17, d['b'] == 100
(2, True, True)
```