# Why do these .append() statements overwrite each other?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I have a function as follows:

```
def control(qstat):
    gatnum = int(input("What number of control gates is this control qubit a part of?"))
    global qstatnum
    qstatnum = {}
    qstatnum[gatnum] = []
    qstatnum[gatnum].append(qstat) #seems to be a problem
    return qstat
```

However, there is a problem. Let's say I run it once. There will be one item in the list. Then, I run it a second time, with an item distinguishable from the second supposed to be added to the list. When I print `qstatnum[gatnum]`, the list contains only the second item, leading me to believe that the `.append()` statement is somehow incorrectly written and overwriting any previous additions to the list.

Is this a correct diagnosis? Why would this be? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `qstatnum = {}` this should be outside the function

Comment: Also `qstatnum[gatnum] = []` is questionable. I would have expected to see `qstatnum.setdefault(gatnum, []).append(qstat)`.

Comment: @DanD., out of curiosity, why is that better, and what exactly does it do? I've never seen `.setdefault` before

Comment: It says if you have a list there, then get it. Otherwise, make an empty one

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method#3483652

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected content for qstatnum?

Comment: @slackmart, sure - `qstatnum = {1:[np.array([0,1]), np.array([1,0])}` in this particular case, but there might be more than one key value pair, obviously, and more or less items in the list.

Comment: @cricket_007, this *seems* to be working, but now an unrelated error is popping up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call the function, you are creating a new `qstatnum` dict, so the solution is to create the dictionary outside the function:

```
qstatnum = {}

def control(qstat):
    gatnum = int(input("What number of control gates is this control qubit a part of?"))
    try:
        qstatnum[qstat].append(gatnum)
    except:
        qstatnum[qstat] = [gatnum]
    return qstat
```

You need a `try: except:` block to verify if the key already exists in the dictionary, if it doesn't exists, just add the first value, else use append.

@DanD. approach seems to be shorter, please take a look:

```
qstatnum = {}

def control(qstat):
    gatnum = int(input("What number of control gates is this control qubit a part of?"))

    qstatnum.setdefault(qstat, []).append(gatnum)

    return qstat
```

Comment: ah, I need to keep the `global qstatnum` line - let me try that.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, and it still gives the exact same error.

Comment: You're still reseting `qstatnum[gatnum] = []`

Comment: @cricket_007, okay - how do I set that but without resetting each time?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected content for qstatnum?

Comment: @slackmart, one example could be `qstatnum = {1:[np.array([1,0]),np.array([0,1])]}`.

Comment: @slackmart, thank you, I think yours and cricket_007's help fixed the problem. +1 and an accept =)

Comment: With DanD.'s approach, wouldn't you still need to include the `global qstatnum` line or no?

Answer (score 0):

Every time the method is called, `qstatnum` is set to empty. So basically you are appending to nothing every time.