# IndexError: list index out of range python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code

```
def retrieve_user(username):

    with open(users_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:

        items = []
        line_num = 0
        for line in f:
            line_num = line_num+1
            #print(items)
            if line_num > 1:
                items = line.split(';')
                name = items[0]
                area = items[1]
                all_keywords = items[2].split('$')

                if name in user.keys():
                    user[name].append([area, all_keywords])
                else:
                    user[name] = [area, all_keywords]

        if username in user.keys():
            print(user[username])
        else:
            print('User ', username, ' could not be found')
            login_user()

    return False
```

and now i get the following error. does anybody knows why? I have stuck and i don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
**area = items[1]
IndexError: list index out of range**
```

the file that i am trying to retrieve the data looks like this

```
user;area;keywords

mike;Sports: Football;Arsenal

john;Technology: IBM;CPU
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have empty lines in the file, if you split a empty line on `;` you do not have an index of 1 in the resulting `item`. Error tells you as much.

Your code is missing crucial codeparts (f.e. the user dict):

Try this:

```
with open(users_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   txt = f.read()

# txt = """user;area;keywords
#
# mike;Sports: Football;Arsenal
# 
# john;Technology: IBM;CPU"""

# split each line on newlines, take only lines thats have non-whitespace in it. 
# split those line at ;
splitted = [x.split(";") for x in txt.splitlines() if x.strip() != ""]
print(splitted)
```

Output:

```
[['user', 'area', 'keywords'], 
 ['mike', 'Sports: Football', 'Arsenal'], 
 ['john', 'Technology: IBM', 'CPU']]
```

Accessing the parsed lists by row:

```
for name, area, words in splitted[1:]:  # skips the first row via list comprehension, 
                                        # and decompose each inner list into name,
                                        # area and words
    all_keywords = words.split("$")
    print(name, "    ", area , "    ", all_keywords)
```

Output:

```
mike      Sports: Football      ['Arsenal']
john      Technology: IBM      ['CPU']
```

If you want to create keys into dictionarys, you can leverage `dict.setdefault(key,defaultvalue)`:

```
if name in user.keys():
    user[name].append([area, all_keywords])
else:
    user[name] = [area, all_keywords]
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
user.setdefault(name,[]).extend([area, all_keywords])
```

This creates the key with an empty list if it does not yet exists. The value is returned by `setdefault` and `extend(...)` adds to it your current data. If the key exists, setdefault simpley returns the value and also extends it. Win-Win: your list grows.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict   or    this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483652/7505395

Comment: @newbie The code reads the complete file into `txt` (if you uncomment `with open(users_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:` and the next line).  `splittet` is a list, each non-empty line in your file is one list-entry and each entry is split at `;`   the `for name,area, words in splitted[1:]:`  skips the "headerrow" and gives you each lines `name`, `area` and `words`. Thats about what you do above, you can use those 3 on your user-dict and do what you need to do