# How to update value of key in nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, append

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'language': 'English', 'name': 'Sarah', 'description': 'Blah blah'}, {'id': 2, 'language': 'English', 'name': 'Jessica', 'description': 'More blah'}]

d = {}
for item in items:

    language = item['language']
    id = item['id']
    name = item['name']
    description = item['description']

    d[language][id] = {'name': name, 'description': description}

print(d)
```

I'm expecting to see in output:

```
{'English': {1:{'name': 'Sarah', 'description': 'Blah blah'}, 2:{'name': 'Jessica', 'description': 'More blah'}}}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting KeyError:
[image: Traceback: KeyError]

**So, the question is how to update/append value in nested dictionary? What I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` does not contain `d["English"]` which you try to create with `d[language][id] = {'name': name, 'description': description}` - hence the error.

---

You cannot create intermediate dictionaries "on the fly" if they do not exist - either check if they already exist and if not create them - or use [dict.setdefault(key,default)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to create the entry if it does not yet exist:

```
items = [{'id': 1, 'language': 'English', 'name': 'Sarah', 'description': 'Blah blah'},
         {'id': 2, 'language': 'English', 'name': 'Jessica', 'description': 'More blah'}]

d = {}
for item in items:
   
    language = item['language']
    idd = item['id']
    name = item['name']
    description = item['description']

    d.setdefault(language,{})[idd] = {'name': name, 'description': description}

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'English': {1: {'name': 'Sarah', 'description': 'Blah blah'}, 
             2: {'name': 'Jessica', 'description': 'More blah'}}}
```

You can use `collections.defaultdict` as well if you come into performance problems using `setdefault` - which is slightly less fast.

---

Related: [Use cases for the 'setdefault' dict method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483520/use-cases-for-the-setdefault-dict-method)

Answer (score 4):

d is an initially empty dictionary, so does not have key language (which is `'English'`) yet when you try to assign a value to `d[language][id]`.

You can change your code as follow:

```
for item in items:

    language = item['language']
    id = item['id']
    name = item['name']
    description = item['description']

    if not language in d:
        d[language] = {}
    d[language][id] = {'name': name, 'description': description}
```