# How to make a dictionary that returns key for keys missing from the dictionary instead of raising KeyError?

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, dictionary-missing

I want to create a python dictionary that returns me the key value for the keys are missing from the dictionary.

Usage example:

```
dic = smart_dict()
dic['a'] = 'one a'
print(dic['a'])
# >>> one a
print(dic['b'])
# >>> b
```

Comment: I was expecting to be able to get this behavior with `collections.defautldict()` but for some reason I'm missing something about how it works.

Comment: There's a number of ways to do this. One possibly important distinction / consideration is whether or not they also add the missing key to the underlying dictionary.

Comment: related: [Is there a clever way to pass the key to defaultdict's default_factory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2912231/3780389)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

`dict`s have a [`__missing__`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) hook for this:

```
class smart_dict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key
```

Could simplify it as (since `self` is never used):

```
class smart_dict(dict):
    @staticmethod
    def __missing__(key):
        return key
```

Comment: Furthermore the docs say "defaultdict objects support [`__missing__`] in addition to the standard dict operations" which is just wrong.

Comment: Why is that wrong?  I'd guess __missing__ is the primary method by which defaultdict works

Comment: Bear in mind that while `smart_dict()['a']` returns `'a'`, `smart_dict().get('a')` returns `None` (or whatever value passed as default), which might not be the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 36):

Why don't you just use

```
dic.get('b', 'b')
```

Sure, you can subclass `dict` as others point out, but I find it handy to remind myself every once in a while that `get` can have a default value!

If you want to have a go at the `defaultdict`, try this:

```
dic = defaultdict()
dic.__missing__ = lambda key: key
dic['b'] # should set dic['b'] to 'b' and return 'b'
```

except... well: `AttributeError: ^collections.defaultdict^object attribute '__missing__' is read-only`, so you will have to subclass:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class KeyDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return key

d = KeyDict()
print d['b'] #prints 'b'
print d.keys() #prints []
```

Comment: Why subclass `defaultdict` vs subclassing `dict`?

Comment: The real usefulness of defaultdict is in cases like dd=defaultdict(list), where you can unconditionally write dd[key].append(item), which is a lot more cumbersome with .get, so this solution to the trivial lookup problem is not always what is needed.

Answer (score 15):

**Congratulations.** You too have discovered the uselessness of the
standard `collections.defaultdict` type. If that execrable midden heap of [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)
offends your delicate sensibilities as much as it did mine, this is your lucky
StackOverflow day.

Thanks to the forbidden wonder of the [3-parameter
variant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) of the `type()`
builtin, crafting a non-useless default dictionary type is both fun and profitable.

### What's Wrong with dict.__missing__()?

Absolutely nothing, assuming you like excess boilerplate and the shocking silliness of `collections.defaultdict` – which *should* behave as expected but really doesn't. To be fair, [Jochen
Ritzel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95612/jochen-ritzel)'s [accepted
solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6229253/2809027) of subclassing `dict` and
implementing the [optional `__missing__()`
method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) *is* a fantastic
workaround for small-scale use cases only requiring a single default dictionary.

But boilerplate of this sort scales poorly. If you find yourself instantiating
multiple default dictionaries, each with their own slightly different logic for
generating missing key-value pairs, an industrial-strength alternative
automating boilerplate is warranted.

Or at least nice. Because why not fix what's broken?

### Introducing DefaultDict

In less than ten lines of pure Python (excluding docstrings, comments, and
whitespace), we now define a `DefaultDict` type initialized with a user-defined
callable generating default values for missing keys. Whereas the callable passed
to the standard `collections.defaultdict` type uselessly accepts *no*
parameters, the callable passed to our `DefaultDict` type usefully accepts the
following two parameters:

1. The current instance of this dictionary.
2. The current missing key to generate a default value for.

Given this type, solving [sorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99834/sorin)'s
question reduces to a single line of Python:

```
>>> dic = DefaultDict(lambda self, missing_key: missing_key)
>>> dic['a'] = 'one a'
>>> print(dic['a'])
one a
>>> print(dic['b'])
b
```

Sanity. *At last.*

### Code or It Didn't Happen

```
def DefaultDict(keygen):
    '''
    Sane **default dictionary** (i.e., dictionary implicitly mapping a missing
    key to the value returned by a caller-defined callable passed both this
    dictionary and that key).

    The standard :class:`collections.defaultdict` class is sadly insane,
    requiring the caller-defined callable accept *no* arguments. This
    non-standard alternative requires this callable accept two arguments:

    #. The current instance of this dictionary.
    #. The current missing key to generate a default value for.

    Parameters
    ----------
    keygen : CallableTypes
        Callable (e.g., function, lambda, method) called to generate the default
        value for a "missing" (i.e., undefined) key on the first attempt to
        access that key, passed first this dictionary and then this key and
        returning this value. This callable should have a signature resembling:
        ``def keygen(self: DefaultDict, missing_key: object) -> object``.
        Equivalently, this callable should have the exact same signature as that
        of the optional :meth:`dict.__missing__` method.

    Returns
    ----------
    MappingType
        Empty default dictionary creating missing keys via this callable.
    '''

    # Global variable modified below.
    global _DEFAULT_DICT_ID

    # Unique classname suffixed by this identifier.
    default_dict_class_name = 'DefaultDict' + str(_DEFAULT_DICT_ID)

    # Increment this identifier to preserve uniqueness.
    _DEFAULT_DICT_ID += 1

    # Dynamically generated default dictionary class specific to this callable.
    default_dict_class = type(
        default_dict_class_name, (dict,), {'__missing__': keygen,})

    # Instantiate and return the first and only instance of this class.
    return default_dict_class()


_DEFAULT_DICT_ID = 0
'''
Unique arbitrary identifier with which to uniquify the classname of the next
:func:`DefaultDict`-derived type.
'''
```

The key <sup>*...get it, **key**?*</sup> to this arcane wizardry is the call to
the [3-parameter variant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)
of the `type()` builtin:

```
type(default_dict_class_name, (dict,), {'__missing__': keygen,})
```

This single line dynamically generates a new `dict` subclass aliasing the
optional `__missing__` method to the caller-defined callable. Note the distinct
lack of boilerplate, reducing `DefaultDict` usage to a single line of Python.

Automation for the egregious win.

Comment: Cool, didn't know the 3-parameter variant! I agree with your sentiment (so `defaultdict` needs a PEP?), however I guess most people would just need a "sane" `defaultdict` without the industrial strength class generation. Actually, why create many classes at all? Why not have the default (callable) as a member of the class? This inspired me to write https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790669/2965879.

Comment: That was exactly my initial thoughts, but then I realized the probable rationale. It seems the author's initial idea was to use constructor like that: `default_str_dict = defaultdict(str)` instead of `default_str_dict = defaultdict('')`. Anyway, this definitely was a poor decision and led to unexpected behavior and inconvenience.

Answer (score 13):

The first respondent mentioned `defaultdict`,
but you can define `__missing__` for any subclass of `dict`:

```
>>> class Dict(dict):
        def __missing__(self, key):
            return key


>>> d = Dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> d['a']
1
>>> d['z']
'z'
```

Also, I like the second respondent's approach:

```
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> d.get('z', 'z')
'z'
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree this should be easy to do, and also easy to set up with different defaults or functions that transform a missing value somehow.

Inspired by [Cecil Curry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809027/cecil-curry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44126972/2965879), I asked myself: why not have the default-generator (either a constant or a callable) as a member of the class, instead of generating different classes all the time? Let me demonstrate:

```
# default behaviour: return missing keys unchanged
dic = FlexDict()
dic['a'] = 'one a'
print(dic['a'])
# 'one a'
print(dic['b'])
# 'b'

# regardless of default: easy initialisation with existing dictionary
existing_dic = {'a' : 'one a'}
dic = FlexDict(existing_dic)
print(dic['a'])
# 'one a'
print(dic['b'])
# 'b'

# using constant as default for missing values
dic = FlexDict(existing_dic, default = 10)
print(dic['a'])
# 'one a'
print(dic['b'])
# 10

# use callable as default for missing values
dic = FlexDict(existing_dic, default = lambda missing_key: missing_key * 2)
print(dic['a'])
# 'one a'
print(dic['b'])
# 'bb'
print(dic[2])
# 4
```

How does it work? Not so difficult:

```
class FlexDict(dict):
    '''Subclass of dictionary which returns a default for missing keys.
    This default can either be a constant, or a callable accepting the missing key.
    If "default" is not given (or None), each missing key will be returned unchanged.'''
    def __init__(self, content = None, default = None):
        if content is None:
            super().__init__()
        else:
            super().__init__(content)
        if default is None:
            default = lambda missing_key: missing_key
        self.default = default # sets self._default

    @property
    def default(self):
        return self._default

    @default.setter
    def default(self, val):
        if callable(val):
            self._default = val
        else: # constant value
            self._default = lambda missing_key: val

    def __missing__(self, x):
        return self.default(x)
```

Of course, one can debate whether one wants to allow changing the default-function after initialisation, but that just means removing `@default.setter` and absorbing its logic into `__init__`.

Enabling introspection into the current (constant) default value could be added with two extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `dict`'s `__getitem__` method.  For example, [How to properly subclass dict and override __getitem__ & __setitem__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390827/how-to-properly-subclass-dict-and-override-get-set)

Answer (score 0):

VERY late to the party, but I'm just bothered with this for so many times, that I thought I'd just research this myself.

The **web** doc say nothing on the exact semantics of this overridable `__missing__` method (and is misleading to some degree), but the `help(defaultdict.__missing__)` (which I doubt if any of us would read) output will actually tell you the information you need:

```
>>> help(defaultdict.__missing__)
Help on method_descriptor:
__missing__(...)
    __missing__(key) # Called by __getitem__ for missing key; pseudo-code:
    if self.default_factory is None: raise KeyError((key,))
    self[key] = value = self.default_factory()
    return value
```

So it's now clear that all `__missing__` in subclass must follow the similar procedure, instead of just a plain `return foo(key)`

Here is an example you can copy from

```py
class MyDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        value = key + 1
        self[key] = value
        return value
```

Replace `key + 1` with the type of transform of your choice.