# python identity dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a python dictionary that returns key for keys missing from the dictionary instead of raising KeyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229073/how-to-make-a-python-dictionary-that-returns-key-for-keys-missing-from-the-dicti)

I need something like a `defaultdict`. However, for any key that isn't in the dictionary, it should return the key itself.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Terminology nitpick: An identity dict is usually taken to be a dictionary that uses object identity (`id`) for keys instead of hashes.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't find the other question. Thanks for pointing it out. Is there a way to consolidate the two questions? The accepted answer to the other question is shown to be wrong though, and the OP didn't bother to change his acceptance.

Comment: @max: there's a Stack Overflow process for handling duplicate questions. It will all get taken care of =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the magic `__missing__` method:

```
>>> class KeyDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...             return key
... 
>>> x = KeyDict()
>>> x[2]
2
>>> x[2]=0
>>> x[2]
0
>>>
```

Answer (score 10):

you mean something like the following?

```
value = dictionary.get(key, key)
```

Comment: +1 one-line solution, no need for classes or overwriting

Comment: The downside to the `get` approach is that you are replicating the "return key when not found" rule all over your code.  If this is a rule for all accesses, then it is best to implement that functionality _once_ in the container itself (see @katrielalex's `__missing__` answer) rather than *k* times throughout the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I neglected to specify that it has to be a dictionary (it's passed to functions that expect to call dictionary methods).

Answer (score 2):

```
class Dict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super(Dict, self).__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            return key

>>> a = Dict()
>>> a[1]
1
>>> a[1] = 'foo'
>>> a[1]
foo
```

This works if you have to support Python < 2.5 (which added the `__missing__` method mentioned by @katrielalex).