# error in dictionary , could not find why i cannot add c

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, typeerror, defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

    
# Defining the dict and passing
# lambda as default_factory argument
d = defaultdict(lambda c: "Not Present")
d["a"] = 1
d["b"] = 2


print(d["a"])
print(d["b"])
print(d["c"])
```

I expected a right outcome
Everything sounds right
Please check whats wrong with C lambda

Comment: *default_factory ... is called without arguments ...* https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Change `lambda c: "Not Present"` to `lambda: "Not Present"` and you'll get the output you want.

Comment: It looks like you don't want a defaultdict but rather a dictionary… `d = {'c': 'Not Present'}`, no? If you want 'Not Present' for all, then `d = defaultdict(lambda : "Not Present")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [lambda function returning the key value for use in defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931783/lambda-function-returning-the-key-value-for-use-in-defaultdict)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the "c" in the lambda. You should use defaultdict like that:

```py
d = defaultdict(lambda: "Not Present")
```

when you put a word after `lambda`, it's an argument. Exemple:

```py
lambda x, y: x + y
```