# Handle missing keys in python dictionary

Tags: python, boto

I'm building a list of EC2 instances in Amazon. And I am testing for the existence of keys called PrivateIpAddress and PublicIpAddress in a dictionary. In some cases neither key exists and I get an exception:

```
-------------------------------------
Instance ID: i-86533615
Type: m4.xlarge
State: stopped
Private IP: 10.1.233.18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(Fore.CYAN + "{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))
KeyError: 'Public IP'
```

My code says:

```
for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
if 'PrivateIpAddress' in instance and 'PublicIpAddress' in instance:
    ... do stuff...
elif 'PrivateIpAddress' in instance:
else:
    ...do stuff..
```

But the last else doesn't catch the problem of an instance not having either a public ip address or a private ip address.

Here is the full code in python: [list ec2 instances](https://pastebin.com/yM0v8GuP)

Comment: you can use reservation.get("Instances",default value here). for example
`reservation.get("Instances",[])`

Comment: so, just in case this was where you were stumped: you can add another elif, which checks for 'PublicIpAddress', you arent limited to just 1 elif. Having said that, this can probably be done cleaner with a `get` or `setdefault` method, as you see fit.

Comment: Couple of ways you could handle this.  You could proactively check the keys that are in the dictionary before you call them by doing something like `if 'Public IP' in instance.keys()` , or use `.get` and supply a default value, or, if you wanted to go overboard, use a `DefaultDict`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a python dictionary that returns key for keys missing from the dictionary instead of raising KeyError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229073/how-to-make-a-python-dictionary-that-returns-key-for-keys-missing-from-the-dicti)

Comment: Your traceback says the error is in ` print(Fore.CYAN + "{0}: {1}".format(key, instance[key]))`, but that's not included in the code that you present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
    private_ip_address = instance.get("PrivateIpAddress" , None)
    public_ip_address = instance.get("PublicIpAddress" , None)
    if  private_ip_address and public_ip_address:
    ... do stuff...
    elif private_ip_address:
       ...do stuff.. 
    else:
       ...do stuff..
```

Try this one

Answer (score 1):

I see a fundamental problem in your logic.  You're looping through all the instances and building up maps for each of them in **ec2info**.  But each time through the loop, when processing a particular instance, you're looping over all the data in **ec2info**, including the data added by previous iterations of the loop.  I bet you don't really want to do this.  I bet you really want to display the attributes for just the instance you're working on.

Here's the key to your problem:

```
attributes = ['Instance ID', 'Type',
    'State', 'Private IP', 'Launch Time' ]
for instance_id, instance in ec2info.items():
```

So here, you're iterating over all the maps in **ec2info**, and yet you're applying a set of 'attributes' that are specific to the one instance you're currently processing.  Since in general, per your own code, not all of the maps in **ec2info** will have all of the same keys, you're getting the error you're getting.