# What is the difference between dict and collections.defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was checking out Peter Norvig's [code](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) on how to write simple spell checkers. At the beginning, he uses this code to insert words into a dictionary.

```
def train(features):
    model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1)
    for f in features:
        model[f] += 1
    return model
```

What is the difference between a Python dict and the one that was used here? In addition, what is the `lambda` for? I checked the API documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and it says that defaultdict is actually derived from dict but how does one decide which one to use?

Comment: What happens if you try that above code using `model = {}` (which is an ordinary dict)?

Comment: A `defaultdict` allows you to specify a function that will generate the default value if a key in the dictionary doesn't exist.

Comment: @Greg Hwegill: Yes. It will generate a key error but I can get around it by using `setdefault` right? Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, could you tell me what the lambda is being used for?

Comment: `dict` and `collections.defaultdict` are both very completely defined in the documentation.  What **specific** questions do you have about the actual words used in the actual documentation?  It seems clear to us.  Can you provide some hint as to what is not clear to you?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The difference is that a `defaultdict` will "default" a value if that key has not been set yet. If you didn't use a `defaultdict` you'd have to check to see if that key exists, and if it doesn't, set it to what you want.

The lambda is defining a factory for the default value. That function gets called whenever it needs a default value. You could hypothetically have a more complicated default function.

```
Help on class defaultdict in module collections:

class defaultdict(__builtin__.dict)
 |  defaultdict(default_factory) --> dict with default factory
 |  
 |  The default factory is called without arguments to produce
 |  a new value when a key is not present, in __getitem__ only.
 |  A defaultdict compares equal to a dict with the same items.
 |
```

(from `help(type(collections.defaultdict()))`)

`{}.setdefault` is similar in nature, but takes in a value instead of a factory function. It's used to set the value if it doesn't already exist... which is a bit different, though.

Answer (score 27):

Courtesy :- https://shirishweb.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/python-defaultdict-versus-dict-get/

**Using Normal dict**

```
d={}
d['Apple']=50
d['Orange']=20
print(d['Apple'])
print(d['Grapes'])# This gives Key Error
```

We can avoid this KeyError by using defaulting in normal dict as well, let see how we can do it

```
d={}
d['Apple']=50
d['Orange']=20
print(d['Apple'])
print(d.get('Apple'))
print(d.get('Grapes',0)) # DEFAULTING
```

**Using default dict**

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int) ## inside parenthesis we say what should be the default value.
d['Apple']=50
d['Orange']=20
print(d['Apple'])
print(d['Grapes']) ##→ This gives Will not give error
```

Using an user defined function to default the value

```
from collections import defaultdict
def mydefault():
        return 0

d = defaultdict(mydefault)
d['Apple']=50
d['Orange']=20
print(d['Apple'])
print(d['Grapes'])
```

**Summary**

1. Defaulting in normal dict is on case to case basis and in defaultdict we can provide default in general manner
2. Efficiency of using defaulting by defaultdict is two time greater than defaulting with normal dict. You can refer below link to know better on this performance testing
   https://shirishweb.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/python-defaultdict-versus-dict-get/

Answer (score 13):

**Let's deep dive into Python dictionary and Python `defaultdict()` class**

### Python Dictionaries

Dict is one of the data structures available in Python which allows data to be stored in the form of key-value pairs.

Example:

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

#### Problem with Dictionary

Dictionaries work well unless you encounter missing keys. Suppose you are looking for a key-value pair where there is no value in the dictionary - then you might encounter a `KeyError` problem. Something like this:

```
d = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
d['z']  # z is not present in dict so it will throw a error
```

You will see something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    d['z'] 
KeyError: 'z'
```

#### Solution to the above problem

To overcome the above problem we can use different ways:

*Using inbuilt functions*

- [`setdefault(key\[, default\])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault)
- [`get(key[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)
- [`defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

##### `setdefault`

If the `key` is in the dictionary, return its value. If not, insert a key with a value of `default` and return `default`. `default` defaults to `None`:

```
>>> d = {'a' :2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
>>> d.setdefault('z', 0)
0  # returns 0 
>>> print(d)  # add z to the dictionary
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, 'z': 0}
```

##### `get`

Return the value for `key` if the key is in the dictionary, else `default`. If the default is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`:

```
>>> d = {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
>>> d.get('z', 0)
0  # returns 0 
>>> print(d)  # Doesn't add z to the dictionary unlike setdefault
{'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}
```

The above 2 methods are the solutions to our problem. It never raises `KeyError`. Apart from the above 2 methods, Python also has a [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module that can handle this problem. Let's dig deep into the `defaultdict` in the collections module:

##### `defaultdict`

`defaultdict` can be found in the collections module of Python. You can use it using:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
```

`defaultdict` constructor takes `default_factory` as an argument that is a callable. This can be for example:

- `int`: default will be an integer value of `0`
- `str`: default will be an empty string `""`
- `list`: default will be an empty list `[]`

##### Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['a']  # access a missing key and returns an empty list
d['b'] = 1 # add a key-value pair to dict
print(d)
```

output will be `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'b': 1, 'a': []})`

#### The `defaultdict` works the same as the `get()` and `setdefault()` methods, so when to use them?

##### When to use `get()`

If you specifically need to return a certain key-value pair without `KeyError` and also it should not update in the dictionary - then `dict.get` is the right choice for you. It returns the default value specified by you but does not modify the dictionary.

##### When to use `setdefault()`

If you need to modify the original dictionary with a default key-value pair - then `setdefault` is the right choice.

##### When to use `defaultdict`

`setdefault` method can be achieved using `defaultdict` but instead of providing default value every time in `setdefault`, we can do it at once in `defaultdict`. Also, `setdefault` has a choice of providing different default values for the keys. Both have their own advantages depending on the use case.

#### When it comes to efficiency:

> `defaultdict` > `setdefault()` or `get()`

`defaultdict` is 2 times faster than `get()`!

You can check the results [here](https://shirishweb.wordpress.com/2017/05/06/python-defaultdict-versus-dict-get/).

Comment: Very nice detailed answer! One problem is ion the `defaultdict` example you give. You create a `defaultdict(list)` but then do `d['b'] = 1`. This loses the point of using a defaultdict. The more idiomatic usecase is when we want to append something to a list without checking if the key already exists. So I would change that example to `d['b'].append(1)` and show that it becomes a list `[1]`

Comment: @Tomerikoo It's a very good example and suits well with the above scenario and thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 11):

Use a defaultdict if you have some meaningful default value for missing keys and don't want to deal with them explicitly.

The defaultdict constructor takes a function as a parameter and constructs a value using that function.

```
lambda: 1
```

is the same as the parameterless function f that does this

```
def f():
 return 1
```

I forgot the reason the API was designed this way instead of taking a value as a parameter.  If I designed the defaultdict interface, it would be slightly more complicated, the missing value creation function would take the missing key as a parameter.

Comment: If you took the value as a parameter you'd have to be careful about mutable values. e.g. `defaultdict([])` would set the same (mutable) list as the value for every missing element, whereas `defaultdict(list)` always creates a new one

Comment: I think the reason that `defaultdict`'s factory function takes no parameters is so it can be used with types whose `__init__()` constructors don't require any -- such as `int`, `list`, and `dict`. You can, of course, easily derive a subclass from `defaultdict` whose `__missing__()` method _does_ pass the key to the factory function. See the answer to [Is there a clever way to pass the key to defaultdict's default_factory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912231/is-there-a-clever-way-to-pass-the-key-to-defaultdicts-default-factory).