# find most frequent words in a list(without frequency no.)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which contains words. I want to know the most frequent words in my list. I tried using 'counter' from collections package.

```
result = Counter(z).most_common(5)
```

and I got this result.

```
result
>>[('abc', 893), ('op', 198), ('bff', 172), ('ppf', 140), ('request', 119)]
```

but I only want the words and not the frequency no. attached with it. like

```
['abc','op','bff','ppf','request']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to extract them from `result`:

```
print([res[0] for res in result])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index and list comprehension:

```
result = Counter(z).most_common(5)
result = [i[0] for i in result]
```

Or in one line:

```
result = [i[0] for i in Counter(z).most_common(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

from [HERE](http://evanmuehlhausen.com/simple-counters-in-python-with-benchmarks/) Counter is slower than  defaultdict. if performance is important try this:

```
import operator
from collections import defaultdict

counter = defaultdict(int)
foods = ['soy', 'dairy', 'gluten', 'soy']
for k in foods:
    counter[k] += 1
most_common = 5
# counter includes a dictionary(without order)
# here we sort dictionary(this may needs more time than above link shows):
result = list(zip(*sorted(counter.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:most_common]))[0]
```

Comment: It's output order is random .. I got output as : `['gluten', 'dairy']` But it should be `['soy', 'dairy']` or `['soy', 'gluten']` and When I try to print counter :`print(counter)` , I got output : `defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'gluten': 1, 'soy': 2, 'dairy': 1})`

Comment: Can we use normal dictionary instead of defaultdict? I tried and it works : `counter = {}
foods = ['soy', 'dairy', 'gluten', 'soy']
for k in foods:
 if k in counter :
  counter[k] += 1
 else:
  counter[k] = 1`  Is there any difference in the performance?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane defaultdict is a normal dict with default value(`int == 0`) see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589814/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-and-collections-defaultdict). your code works but i think checking conditions are slow:)