# default dictionary difference to dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question for my understanding of the below code.
I understand the difference between a normal dict and a defaultdict, but my question is that with the below code, when I replace defaultdict with just dict() or {}, I get a KeyValue error for 7 (the first number in the list), why is this?

Surely it shouldn't return an error when called, because 7 is in the list?? Thanks

```
nums = [7,6,7,12]

class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums):
        hash_table = defaultdict(int)      
                      
        for i in nums:
            hash_table[i] += 1       

        print(hash_table)

        for i in hash_table:
            if hash_table[i] == 1:         
                return i


x = Solution()
print(x.singleNumber(nums))
```

Comment: `hash_table[i] += 1` fails on dict if `i` is not in the dict. And there is noting in a new dict.

Comment: You can't increment something that's not there. Read more about how `collections.defaultdict` works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900578/how-does-collections-defaultdict-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between dict and collections.defaultdict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589814/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-and-collections-defaultdict)

Comment: "Surely it shouldn't return an error when called, because 7 is in the list?" What does it being in the list have to do with the *dictionary key* error? A key error tells you it isn't *in the dict* which is true 
 Can you explain what you think the difference is between a defaultdict and a regular dict, because *this case is the important difference*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `7` is in your list `nums`, but it isn't automatically in the dictionary.

The line
`hash_table[i] += 1`
looks up the value of `i` in `hash_table`, adds one to it, and then changes the value in the `hash_table`. But it can't look up the value of `7` in `hash_table` if `hash_table` is an ordinary dictionary, because `7` was never added to the dictionary.

With a `defaultdict`, the code works because when it tries to look up the value `7` in `hash_table`, it discovers that `7` is not in the `hash_table` yet, and so it returns the default value, which in this case is `0`. It then adds `1` to that, and then changes the value in the dictionary.