# What is the alternative of unorderd_map in python? We know that default value in key: value is zero in c++

Tags: c++, python-3.x

```
//in C++
unordered_map<int,int>m;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          m[arr[i]]++;
}

#in python
my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(arr)):
       my_dict[arr[i]] += 1 #This gives key error
```

I am sure that the default value is set to zero in C++, so it works.
How to go about it in Python?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161752/how-to-count-the-frequency-of-the-elements-in-an-unordered-list

Answer (score 2):

In python you could use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [1,2,3]

my_dict = defaultdict(int)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    my_dict[arr[i]]+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Loocid suggested `defaultdict` is the way to go. The other option is to use `get()` with a default value:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(arr)):
    my_dict[arr[i]] = my_dict.get(arr[i], 0) + 1
```

or avoid the indexing with

```
my_dict = {}
for a in arr:
    my_dict[a] = my_dict.get(a, 0) + 1
```

*Written with a smartphone and unchecked*

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is [`defaultdict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6589814/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-and-collections-defaultdict). You can use a function to set a default value.

Example :

```
from collections import defaultdict

def not_inside_dict():
    return 0;

d = defaultdict(not_inside_dict)

d[1] = 7
d[2] = 9

for i in range(1,4):
    print(d[i])
```

Result:

```
7
9
0
```

You can also declare like this :

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

d[1] = 7
d[2] = 9

for i in range(1,4):
    print(d[i])
```

And it will still return `0` when encountering elements not inside the dict.