# How to convert rows of a CSV data to a dict, where the non-unique key-value pairs are parsed from each row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a CSV file, and I want to convert it in to dict format. In the CSV there are paths which are non unique.

my_csv.csv:

```
folder/1/img/file/1.mp3/4.jpg
folder/1/img/file/1.mp3/8.jpg
folder/3/img/file/3.mp3/1.jpg
folder/3/img/file/3.mp3/5.jpg
folder/6/img/file/6.mp3/6.jpg
folder/6/img/file/6.mp3/8.jpg
folder/7/img/file/7.mp3/9.jpg
```

Expected output:

```
expected_output = {
  'folder/1/img/file/1.mp3': ['4.jpg','8.jpg'],
  'folder/3/img/file/3.mp3': ['1.jpg','5.jpg'],
  'folder/6/img/file/6.mp3': ['6.jpg','8.jpg'],
  'folder/7/img/file/7.mp3': ['9.jpg']
}
```

I have tried this,but it could only add one image per folder.

```
import csv

my_dict = {}

with open("my_csv.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvreader:
        for rw in row:  
            head_tail = os.path.split(rw)
            img_path = (head_tail[0])
            img_name = (head_tail[1])
            my_dict[img_path]=img_name
print(my_dict)
```

Comment: `1.mp3/4.jpg` - and why should mp3 file contain jpg file (semantically) ?

Comment: Break your problem into smaller sub-tasks. Have you tried looping through each row of your CSV? Then parsing splitting-off the part of the path after the `/`? Then adding a new key-value pair to a dict? Or updating an existing key in a dict?

Comment: I have added whatever I have tried. Sorry I have missed that one

Comment: 1.mp3/4.jpg    Its in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

This is where Python's [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) becomes useful.

The problem with your loop is that you needed to collect the values for the same key into a list, but you kept resetting the value of `my_dict[img_path]` to just the most recently parsed `img_name`. With a `defaultdict`, if the key doesn't exist yet, it can automatically initialize a default value, which in this case, you can make it an empty list. And then just keep `.append`-ing to that list when you encounter the same key.

Demo:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> dd = defaultdict(list)
>>> dict(dd)
{}
>>> dd["folder/1/img/file/1.mp3"].append("4.jpg")
>>> dd["folder/1/img/file/1.mp3"].append("8.jpg")
>>> 
>>> dd["folder/1/img/file/6.mp3"].append("6.jpg")
>>> 
>>> dict(dd)
{'folder/1/img/file/1.mp3': ['4.jpg', '8.jpg'], 'folder/1/img/file/6.mp3': ['6.jpg']}
```

Putting that into your code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("my_csv.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in csvreader:
        for rw in row:
            img_path, img_name = rw.rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)
            my_dict[img_path].append(img_name)

pprint(dict(my_dict))
```

```
{'folder/1/img/file/1.mp3': ['4.jpg', '8.jpg'],
 'folder/3/img/file/3.mp3': ['1.jpg', '5.jpg'],
 'folder/6/img/file/6.mp3': ['6.jpg', '8.jpg'],
 'folder/7/img/file/7.mp3': ['9.jpg']}
```

Note that if you *strictly* need a regular `dict` type, you can [convert a `defaultdict` to a `dict` by calling `dict(...)` on it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20428636/2745495). But for most purposes, [a `defaultdict` behaves like a `dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6589814/2745495).

Notice that I also changed how to parse the `img_path` and `img_name` on each line. Since those lines don't look like valid paths anyway and that you are not really using them in any file I/O operations, there is no point using `os.path`. You can simply use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit).

Lastly, you say that your input file is a CSV and you are using `csv.reader`, but the contents aren't really CSV-formatted in the sense that it's basically one input string per line. You can do away with regular iteration over each line:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("my_csv.csv", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        img_path, img_name = line.rstrip().rsplit("/", maxsplit=1)
        my_dict[img_path].append(img_name)

pprint(dict(my_dict))
```

...which yields the same result:

```
{'folder/1/img/file/1.mp3': ['4.jpg', '8.jpg'],
 'folder/3/img/file/3.mp3': ['1.jpg', '5.jpg'],
 'folder/6/img/file/6.mp3': ['6.jpg', '8.jpg'],
 'folder/7/img/file/7.mp3': ['9.jpg']}
```