# Python - Using defaultdict to make dictionary of custom objects

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have created the following class. Package, website and comments are all strings and distroDict is a (string, list) dictionary.

```
class TableEntry(object):

    def __init__(self, package, website, distroDict, comments):
        self.package = package
        self.website = website
        self.distroDict = distroDict
        self.comments = comments
```

I want to use defaultdict(TableEntry) to make a (string, TableEntry) custom dictionary.

```
tableDict = defaultdict(TableEntry)
entry = TableEntry(package, website, distroDict, comments)
tableDict[package].append(entry)
```

I want the package to be the key and the entry object to be the value. I can use values within the entry object but if I try to append it to tableDict I receive the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wiki.py", line 151, in <module>
    printMetaData(lines, f)
  File "wiki.py", line 73, in printMetaData
    tableDict[package].append(entry)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
tableDict[package].append(TableEntry(package, website, distroDict, comments))
```

And receive the same error essentially:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wiki.py", line 150, in <module>
    printMetaData(lines, f)
  File "wiki.py", line 73, in printMetaData
    tableDict[package].append(TableEntry(package, website, distroDict, comments))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 5 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Isn't this a list of table entries, so don't you want of `defaultdict(list)` that you are `append`ing `TableEntry`s to? Default dict expects a zero parameter function for creating it's default value, so you can't actually do `defaultdict(TableEntry)`.

Comment: @AChampion wouldnt `defaultdict(list)` give me a dict with { string, [list] }? Whereas I am looking for a dict with { string, TableEntry }. I need to map a String to an object than can hold multiple pieces of information and a string, list dict will not suffice. If I cannot do `defaultdict(TableEntry)` how else could I accomplish this?

Comment: `defaultdist(list)` will give you a a { string: [] } dictionary but as you are appending a `TableEntry`s you needed a collection, e.g. a dictionary of { string: [TableEntry, TableEntry, ...]}. However, if you just want a dictionary of `{string: TableEntry}` why do you need a `defaultdict`, wouldn't `tableDict = {}; tableDict[package] = TableEntry(...)` not work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you try to get something from a defaultdict it returns an instance of the [`default_factory`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory) you instantiated it with, which in your case is `TableEntry` that has no method `append`. But that's actually not why you are getting the error. This happens because when an instance is returned it is also evaluated, and since `TableEntry` doesn't have the arguments it needs, the Python interpreter will complain. But even if `TableEntry` was given arguments in the `defaultdict` call, you would probably get a `TypeError` because `defaultdict` needs to be called with a callable (and not an instance of a class, as it would be).

In summary, you cant instantiate a defaultdict with an non-callable [unless you use subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912231/is-there-a-clever-way-to-pass-the-key-to-defaultdicts-default-factory). Instead you should do something like this:

```
class TableEntry(object):
    def add(self, package, website, distroDict, comments):
        self.package = package
        self.website = website
        self.distroDict = distroDict
        self.comments = comments

tableDict = defaultdict(TableEntry)
entry = ("package", "website", "distroDict", "comments")
tableDict["package"].add(*entry)
```

Then you can do e.g. `tableDict["package"]["website"]` to get the string you wrote to `self.website`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to make the arguments optional for the `__init__` method, and assign the entry object to tableDict directly.

```
class TableEntry:
    def __init__(self, package=None, website=None, distroDict=None, comments=None):
        self.package = package
        self.website = website
        self.distroDict = distroDict
        self.comments = comments

tableDict = defaultdict(TableEntry)
tableDict["package"] = TableEntry("package", "website", "distroDict", "comments")
```