# Lambda in deafaultdict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm following the book 'Data Science from Scratch' and this is a piece of code in it:

```
dd_pair = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
dd_pair[2][1] = 1                       # now dd_pair contains {2: [0, 1]}
```

Can someone please help me understand why and how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultdict` takes a data-type as an initializer. Let's consider we have a dictionary called "users" with "ID" being key and a list as value.
We have to check if a "ID" exists in the dictionary, if yes we append something to the list, else we put an empty list in that place.

So with a regular dictionary, we do something like:

```
users = {}

if "id1" not in users:
    users["id1"] = []
users["id1"].append("log")
```

Now with defaultdict, all we have to do is to set an initialiser as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
users = defaultdict(list)  # Any key not existing in the dictionary will get assigned a `list()` object, which is an empty list
users["id1"].append("log")
```

So coming to your code,

```
dd_pair = defaultdict(lambda: [0, 0])
```

This says, any key which doesn't exist in `dd_pair` will get a list of two elements initialised to `0` as their initial value. So if you just do `print(dd_pair["somerandomkey"])` it should print `[0,0]`.

Therefore, `dd_pair[2][1]` translates roughly to look like this:

```
dd_pair[2] = [0,0] # dd_pair looks like: {2:[0,0]}
dd_pair[2][1] = 1  # dd_pair looks like: {2:[0,1]}
```

> Why the need for `lambda`, why not just use [0,0] ?

The `defaultdict` constructor expects a `callable` (The constructor actually expects a `default_factory`, check out Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects)). In extremely simple terms, if we do `defaultdict(somevar)`, `somevar()` should be valid.

So, if you just pass `[0,0]` to `defaultdict` it'll be wrong since `[0,0]()` is not valid at all.
So what you need is a function which returns `[0,0]`, which can be simply implemented using `lambda:[0,0]`. (To verify, just do `(lambda:[0,0])()` , it will return `[0,0]`).

One more way is to create a class for your specific type, which is better explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36320098/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already understand this part. What I don't understand is the lambda's purpose; Why can't I just write [0,0] without the 'lambda'? What does it do exactly?

Comment: Edited the answer to include that explanation.