# Find a value of a dictionary in dataframe column and modify it

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, any

I dealing with DataFrames and Dictionaries now, and i have a problem, 
I have a Dictionary "*Fruits*"

```
{BN:'Banana', LM:'Lemon', AP:'Apple' ..... etc}
```

And a DataFrame- "*Stock*":

```
   Fruit             Price
0  Sweet Mango           1
1  Green Apple           2
2  Few blue Banana       0
3  Black Banana          5
```

I wand to do the next thing:
replace all the values from `Stock['Fruit']` with the `Fruits.values()` this way:
if the value from Fruits appears in the `Stock['Fruit']` row it will be replaced this way:

Few blue **Banana** --->  **Banana**

Black **Banana** --->  **Banana**

now the DataFrame *Stock* will look this way:

```
   Fruit             Price
0  Sweet Mango           1
1  Green Apple           2
2  Banana                0
3  Banana                5
```

I found different codes to replace or to check if values from the Dicitionary appears in the DataFrame

```
Stock['Fruit'] = Stock.Fruit.map(Fruits)

if (Fruits.values() in Stock['Fruit'] for item in Stock)

any('Mango' in Stock['Fruit'] for index,item in Stock.iterrows())
```

But i cant find any thing to update the rows of the DataFrame

Comment: Why is `Green Apple` not replaced with `Apple`?

Comment: i just gave an example of what i want

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking why you don't change `Green Apple` to `Apple`, but you *do* change `Black Banana` to `Banana` in your output above

Comment: Does my answer include your desired output? If not, can you clarify what your complete desired output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string methods for condition and extracting required values,

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(d.values()))
cond = df['Fruit'].str.contains('|'.join(d.values()))
df.loc[cond, 'Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].str.extract((pat), expand = False)

    Fruit       Price
0   Sweet Mango 1
1   Apple       2
2   Banana      0
3   Banana      5
```

Edit: As @user3483203 suggested, you can fill the missing values with original once the pattern is extracted.

```
df['Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].str.extract(pat).fillna(df.Fruit)
```

Comment: Or just `df.Fruit.str.extract(pat).fillna(df.Fruit)`.  You also don't need to specify the `expand=False`, because you only have a single capture group

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use `apply()` with a custom function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Sweet Mango', 1],['Green Apple', 2],['Few blue Banana', 0],['Black Banana', 5]],
  columns=['Fruit','Price'])

fruits = {'BN':'Banana', 'LM': 'Lemon', 'AP':'Apple', 'MG': 'Mango'}

def find_category(x):

  return [k for k in fruits.values() if k in x][0]

df['Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].apply(find_category)
```

Yields:

```
    Fruit  Price
0   Mango      1
1   Apple      2
2  Banana      0
3  Banana      5
```

Comment: ‘apply()’ will be most efficient if dealing with larger dataframes.

Comment: @rahlf23 tnx, it works for the dataframe and dictionary i've gave as example, now i've tried to do this with another one, and there is a problem:   the new dictionary `states = {'OH': 'Ohio', 'KY': 'Kentucky', 'AS': 'American Samoa', 'NV': 'Nevada'...} ` and a dataframe with columns ` State and Region` the state also contains few words that i want to replace with one word. when i copied your code and only changed the variables it gives me a mistake: `----> 5     return [k for k in states.values() if k in x][0]
IndexError: list index out of range`  when i deleted the `[0]`

Comment: @rahlf23 when i deleted the `[0]` it gives me a "good" dataframe but with the next problems: ` State RegionName
0 [] Auburn
1 [Alabama] Florence
2 [] Jacksonville
3 [Alabama] Livingston
4 [] Montevallo
5 [] Troy
6 [Alabama] Tuscaloosa
7 [] Tuskegee
8 [Alaska] Fairbanks
9 [Arizona] Flagstaff` as you can see it skips some of the values and added "[]" to all the others

Comment: @JLuxton  the one that i use is much bigger, i just practised with small one =)

Comment: @JLuxton `apply` will almost certainly be slower for larger dataframes than other options.  *Especially* since this is an O(n*k) solution.  You'd have better luck with a list comprehension, even `[find_category(x) for x in df.Fruit]` would be vastly more performant, but the algorithm itself will bottleneck performance at that point

Comment: @B.Kristina This solution will return `[]` if there are no exact matches in the values of your dictionary. The reason for the `[0]` is to return the first match (as I am assuming that your values will be unique and not be valid for multiple keys). If you remove `[0]`, then it will return the list of keys that contained that value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the results of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912231/is-there-a-clever-way-to-pass-the-key-to-defaultdicts-default-factory), we create a new class that subclasses `defaultdict`, and override its `__missing__` attribute to allow for passing the key to the `default_factory`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class keydefaultdict(defaultdict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        else:
            ret = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
            return ret
```

We create an initial dictionary that maps the 2 values in the `'Fruits'` column we want to replace.

```
fruit_dict = {'Few blue Banana': 'Banana', 'Black Banana': 'Banana'}
```

Then we create a new instance of our class with a `default_factory` of `lambda x: x`. I.e., if we don't find the key when we search for it, put the key in as the value.

```
fruit_col_map = keydefaultdict(lambda x: x)
fruit_col_map.update(**fruit_dict)
```

Finally, update the column:

```
df['Fruit'] = df['Fruit'].map(fruit_col_map)
df
```

Output:

```
         Fruit  Price
0  Sweet Mango      1
1  Green Apple      2
2       Banana      0
3       Banana      5
```

Comparing to the accepted answer, this is more than 6 times faster:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Sweet Mango', 'Green Apple', 'Few blue Banana', 'Black Banana']*1000,
    'Price': [1, 2, 0, 5]*1000
})
%timeit df['Fruit'].map(fruit_col_map)
```

Results:

```
1.03 ms ± 48.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Accepted answer:

```
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(fruit_dict.values()))
%timeit df['Fruit'].str.extract(pat).fillna(df['Fruit'])
```

Results:

```
6.85 ms ± 223 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```